# Nested Looping JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I receive a valid json object for error messages from the server. I would like to loop through each error and nicely display the error in the web page. Here is example of the json from the server

```
{  
   "contract.cashPrice":[  
      "Cash price is required"
   ],
   "contract.cashDownPayment":[  
      "Cash down payment is required"
   ],
   "contract.effectiveDate":[  
      "Effective date is required"
   ],
   "contract.firstPaymentDate":[  
      "First payment date is required"
   ],
   "contract.mode":[  
      "Mode is required"
   ],
   "contract.numberOfPayments":[  
      "Number of payments is required"
   ],
   "contract.financeChargePercent":[  
      "Finance charge percent is required"
   ]
}
```

when i loop through this error object, i am only able to receive the object property, but not the values. below is the stub code i have written so far. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 for(var error in errors){
        error.forEach(function(message){
             console.log(message);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error` is a key in the `errors` object. You have to use it to access the arrays in `errors`.

```
for (var error in errors) {
  errors[error].forEach(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
}
```

Comment: that was a dangerously quick answer and saves my day. thank you.